# headers already sent due to file structure

Tags: php

### Before anyone marks this as duplicate. I know the reason for the error and it's due to my structure.. I want help to get around this.

Firstly I am trying to make a somewhat dynamic website so for my `index.php` I am using this:

```
<?php
    include '../../includes/functions.php';
    sec_session_start();
    include 'headers/set_session_variables.php';

    include "headers/header.php";
    include "headers/navbar.php";


    $view = 'index';
    if (!empty($_GET['view'])) {
        $tmp_view = basename($_GET['view']);

        if (file_exists("templates/{$tmp_view}.php")) {
                $view = $tmp_view;
        }
    }

    include "templates/{$view}.php";

    include "headers/footer.php";
?>
```

which simply looks at the get request (`index.php?view=profile` for example) and checks if there is a template file, if so display it.

In my profile template I have the display of the profile and editing of the profile.

At the top of the profile page I include a file the deals with post data called `form_actions.php`

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['type'])) {
    $switch = $_POST['type'];

    switch($switch) {
        case 'create_team':
            $team = new teams();
            $return_msg = $team->create_team($db, $_POST['team_name'], $_POST['abb_team_name'], $_POST['p'], $_POST['website'], $_POST['team_logo'], $userID);
            break;
        case 'edit_profile':
            $edit_profile = new edit_user_profile($db, $_POST['firstname'], $_POST['lastname'], $_POST['location'], $_POST['age'], $_POST['facebook'], $_POST['twitter'], $_POST['youtube'],
                $_POST['instagram'], $_POST['website'], $_POST['profilePicOld'], $_POST['headerPicOld'], $_FILES["profilepic"], $_FILES["profileheader"], $userID);
            $return_msg = $edit_profile->update_profile();
            header('Refresh: 2; URL=?view=profile&pid='.$username);
            break;
        default:
    }
}
```

However due to this structure the redirect after editing a profile of course causes:

> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (...)

Is there any way to get around this or is it as simple as the structure is going to keep this from working?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try starting your code with `ob_start()` - it's a bit of a hack but it works. You can then do other things - my `ob_start` includes stripping redundant whitespace from the HTML, for instance. Also fair warning: a user may call `index.php?view=../../some/other/path/file` to execute an arbitrary PHP file, which is a huge problem if you happen to have file uploads.

Comment: Have you tried writing plain JS code which redirects on another page ? Like `echo '<script>window.location = " ' . $url . ' "</script>'`

Comment: Can You make some variable that if passed to view renders HTML redirect tag? Eg.`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />`

Comment: basically, do not render your view files before everything is settled. view should be the last thing to render.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol where do I need to put ob_start? I tried it at the start of my `form_actions.php` and didn't work

Comment: @tektiv that worked fine for me thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it worked for you, I put the code here as an answer (which is not the best, bust still works) :

If the headers have already been sent, you can write some javascript code to [redirect to antoher page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) and then `echo` it via your PHP code like this :

```
case 'edit_profile':
    $edit_profile = new edit_user_profile($db, $_POST['firstname'], $_POST['lastname'], $_POST['location'], $_POST['age'], $_POST['facebook'], $_POST['twitter'], $_POST['youtube'],
        $_POST['instagram'], $_POST['website'], $_POST['profilePicOld'], $_POST['headerPicOld'], $_FILES["profilepic"], $_FILES["profileheader"], $userID);
    $return_msg = $edit_profile->update_profile();
    echo '<script text="text/javascript">window.location = "index.php?view=profile&pid=' . $username . '"</script>';
    break;
```

---

#### If you think you'll do it several times you could create your own function :

```
function redirect($url)
{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "' . $url . '"</script>';
}
```